# How regular is the density of an Itô diffusion?

Tags: probability

Let $(X_t)$ that solve $dX_t=f(X_t)dt+dW_t$ where $f$ is Lipschitz with linear growth. Can we know how regular is $t\mapsto p(x,t)$ ?where $p(x,t)$ is the density function of $X_t$. Like, is it at least $\mathcal C^2$ ? I can't find any reference of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regularity of the density function $p(x, t)$, if it exists, can be studied in terms of the regularity of the solution of the [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation). For different functions $f$, this equation has different properties. A survey on this topic is provided in the book by G.A. Pavliotis [Stochastic Processes and Applications.](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781493913220) In particular, Chapter 4 is entirely devoted to the Fokker-Planck equation, to when it admits a solution and, in this case, to its properties.